# Mule4 - How to specify specific time interval in scheduler cron job?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I an new to setting cron job in Mule4 scheduler.
My requirement is I want my scheduler to run every 15 minutes daily from 6am to 8:45pm.

Though I am able to set the job to run every 15 minutes by - 
    0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *

But I am not able to set the time duration from 6am to 8:45pm.

Can any one please provide your expert guidance please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 0 0/15 6-20 1/1 * ? *
```

- Third parameter identify's hours.
- '-' used for specify ranges.

With this configuration job runs until 20:45.

For detailed explanation, you can check the link below (**8. Cron Triggers**):
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/quartz/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/